# How to reformat data stored in a record and output it in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's go about this with an example

Let's say my table column holds the following data

```
   Col_ID  Col_Name
   ------  ---------------------------------------------------
   102     LOCATION_ID IN (7351,7550,76202,7350)
   121     265,76700,76701,72701,74210)
   111     ,76200,76201,76202,76203,76204,76205,76206,76207,7
```

The above data is stored in that manner in the tables already which cannot be changed. The output that I desire is as follows:-

```
     Col_ID Col_Name
     ------ --------
        102     7531
        102     7550
        102    76202
        102     7350
        121      265
        121    76700
```

And So on.....

Comment: You know already that this is a very bad table design. I wouldn't even consider using SQL in order to solve this. Use a programming language instead, read a record, split the string (in a loop or a split function the programming language may feature), read the next record...

Comment: The issue here is that I can't change the existing data

Comment: Yes I understand that. The data comes from outside in that format. So for the DBMS this is just a string. The DBMS is and should be oblivious as to its content. Interpret the data outside. Use a programming langauge.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - if this problem is solvable in SQL so why not use it?

Comment: @APC: Because the format may change some day (say allowing for `'123 + 124'` or `'123-127'` or semicolons or whatever). This is nothing the DBMS should be concerned with. If you store mere strings then treat them as mere strings. If you want information on separate values in the DBMS then store separate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [multiple ways of extracting data from a delimited string](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings#t=201709141405407224393).

One of which is to use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```
WITH data ( col_id, col_name, lvl, max_lvl, value ) AS (
  SELECT col_id,
         col_name,
         1,                                                  -- First level
         REGEXP_COUNT( col_name, '\d+' ),                    -- Count the number of numbers
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( col_name, '\d+', 1, 1 ) ) -- Extract the first number
  FROM   your_table
  WHERE  1 <= REGEXP_COUNT( col_name, '\d+' )                -- Check there is a number
UNION ALL              -- Iterate over the previous rows
  SELECT col_id,
         col_name,
         lvl + 1,      -- Increase the level by one       
         max_lvl,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( col_name, '\d+', 1, lvl + 1 ) )
                       -- Extract the (lvl+1)th number from the string.
  FROM   data
  WHERE  lvl < max_lvl -- Continue until all the numbers have been parsed
)
SELECT col_id,
       value
FROM   data;
```

Comment: @Maxwell The top part of the recursive sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause determines how many numbers there are in your string (using the `\d+` regular expression with `REGEXP_COUNT`) and gets the first one (using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with the `\d+` regular expression). The second half just iterates over the previous rows increasing the level by one and finding the next number until the level reaches the maximum level (and all the numbers have been found). The final `SELECT` just filters the output down to the two columns you are interested in.

Comment: I am able to get the desired output, but what if I wish to create a view of the output, how do I do that? @MT0

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis is removed with some pattern, so try as below and make necessary modifications.

```
WITH outer_table 
     AS (SELECT col_id, col_name 
           FROM (SELECT col_id, 
                        REGEXP_SUBSTR (col_name, 
                                       '[^)]+', 
                                       1, 
                                       1) 
                           col_name 
                   FROM t5 
                  WHERE col_name LIKE '%)%' 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT col_id, 
                        REGEXP_SUBSTR (col_name, 
                                       '[^(]+', 
                                       1, 
                                       2) 
                           col_name 
                   FROM t5 
                  WHERE col_name LIKE '%(%' 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT col_id, (col_name) col_name 
                   FROM t5 
                  WHERE col_name NOT LIKE '%(%' AND col_name NOT LIKE '%)%')) 
    select col_id, regexp_substr(col_name,'[^,]+',1,column_value) col_name 
     from  outer_table, 
           table( 
                 cast( 
                     multiset( 
                              select  level 
                                from  dual 
                                connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(col_name,'[^,]')) + 1 
                             ) 
                     as sys.OdciNumberList 
                    ) 
               ) 
  ORDER BY col_id,col_name
```

[Demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_EYTCLJZII7ZGAT3X4KD2157T5.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T AS
(SELECT '102' AS COL_ID, 'LOCATION_ID IN (7351,7550,76202,7350)' AS       COL_NAME
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '121', '265,76700,76701,72701,74210)'
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '111', ',76200,76201,76202,76203,76204,76205,76206,76207,7'
FROM   DUAL)
SELECT COL_ID, COL_NAME
FROM   (SELECT T.COL_ID,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.COL_NAME, '[^,]+', 1,
                                         T1.COLUMN_VALUE), '[0-9]+', 1, 1) AS COL_NAME
     FROM   T,
            TABLE(CAST(MULTISET
                        (SELECT LEVEL
                         FROM   DUAL
                         CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                    REGEXP_COUNT(T.COL_NAME, ',') + 1) AS
                        SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST)) T1)
WHERE  COL_NAME IS NOT NULL
```